# Sqlalchemy - Can flushed data be shared bewteen transactions using read uncommited isolation level?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to read data from a table, but this data was not commited only flushed. How can I read this record?

This read is important to my integration test to work, I already set the engine isolation level to read uncommited, but is not working.

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine(
    "url",
    pool_size=os.getenv('POOL_SIZE', 20),
    max_overflow=10,
    isolation_level="READ UNCOMMITTED")


def get_engine():
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    return Session()
```

Read the flushed data.

Comment: why do you `import absolute_import` ?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you targetting?